# Macro not filtering dates

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

When I use the filter in the Excel interface, I can sort dates correctly. However, I cannot get AutoFilter to work using VBA. When I run the macro, every row is filtered out. This also happens when I reuse a recorded macro from a filtering that worked.

The basic macro (I have tried different combinations of criteria!) is:

```
Sub FilterDates1()

    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=8, _
    Criteria1:=">" & Format([31/12/2018], "dd/mm/yyyy"), _
    Criteria2:="<=" & Format([31/12/2019], "dd/mm/yyyy")

End Sub
```

The macro from the Recorder is:

```
Sub FilterDates2()

    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$U$1450").AutoFilter Field:=8, _
    Criteria1:=">31/12/2018", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=31/12/2019"

End Sub
```

But as I say, this also filters out every row.

The formatting of the cells is correct, but there are some cells with invalid entries (e.g. "Cancelled"). As this is user-entered data, I need a macro that can allow for invalid entries.

Help gratefully received!

Comment: `Format("31/12/2019", "dd/mm/yyyy")` `Format([31/12/2019], "dd/mm/yyyy")` gives 30/12/1899 as it evaluates `[` to 31 divided by 12 divided by 2019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Format("31/12/2019", "dd/mm/yyyy")`

`Format([31/12/2019], "dd/mm/yyyy")` gives 30/12/1899 as it evaluates `[` to 31 divided by 12 divided by 2019

Comment: Thanks @Nathan_Sav - that's news to me and solved it. Though first after I also changed the date format to `"mm/dd/yyyy"`, even though it is `"dd/mm/yyyy"` in the sheet!